# How to write a Mac PCL Printer Driver?

Tags: macos, driver, postscript, printer-control-language, cups

I am currently developing printer drivers for Mac which should support both PS (postscript) and PCL printers. I already have an idea about supporting PS (by defining custom CUPS postscript filters in the PPD, and a PDE).

What I don't have an idea about is supporting PCL printers.

a) Is PCL automatically supported by CUPS?

b) If answer to a) is YES, will my PS filter be called when printing to a PCL printer? (I add some PJL to the print data in my PS filter).

c) If anwer to a) is NO, then how should I implement support for PCL? (I need to add some PJL to the PCL data that will be sent to printer).

Answer (score 0):

have you seen https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/SampleRaster/Introduction/Intro.html
?

After fiddling around with Xcode build paths and build settings I got it to work. Its a complete printer driver with cups backend and filter.

kind regards,

Robert